# HTML5 video not returning to poster image using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a video with a poster image and overlay content. The video requests full screen when user clicks custom play button.  If the user exits full screen, the video is reloaded and the overlay content returns.  Everything is working great except the poster image is not returning.  Can anyone help me with this?

The javascript/jQuery is:

```
var featuredButton = $('.featured-panel .play img');
var featuredOverlay = $('.featured-panel .overlay-content');
var featuredVideo = $('.featured-video');
var featuredDown = $('.featured-panel .down');

// when clicking play button
featuredButton.on('click', function() {
  // hide play button
  $(this).hide();
  // hide down button
  featuredDown.hide();
  // hide overlay content
  featuredOverlay.fadeOut();
  // play the video
  $(this).parent().siblings(featuredVideo)[0].play();

  if (win.width() > 1024) {
    // vv This will automatically request full screen, consider using this and then returning to default poster view when full screen is exited
    $(this).parent().siblings(featuredVideo)[0].webkitRequestFullScreen();
    $(this).parent().siblings(featuredVideo)[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
});

featuredVideo.bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
  var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
  var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

  if (event == "FullscreenOff") {
    //do something when fullscreen off
    featuredVideo.load();
    featuredOverlay.fadeIn();
    featuredButton.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: would be much easier to help if you provided your HTML, CSS... like sort of a *demo*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the `fullscreenchange` event on `document` or `window` instead of `<video>`. 
According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange)

> ### fullscreenchange
>
> #### **General info**
>
> **Specification**            Fullscreen Interface
>   **Event Bubbles**          Yes
>   **Cancelable**                No
>   **Target**                        **Document**
>   **Default Action**          None

Also note that your first call to `.webkitRequestFullScreen();`will raise an error in Firefox, which, I think, will make it stops executing the script.

here is a better polyfill :

```js
if(element.requestFullScreen)
    element.requestFullScreen();
    else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen)
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen)
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
            else if(element.msRequestFullscreen)
                element.msRequestFullscreen();
                else console.warn("fullscreen API not supported by this browser")
```

Here is a sample code with assumptive html, so I commented the `featuredDown` parts.
**It will not work in here**, but try this on your machine, it will. (fullscreeen requests are blocked inside the iframes of snippets.)

```js
var featuredButton = $('.featured-panel .play img');
var featuredOverlay = $('.featured-panel .overlay-content');
var featuredVideo = $('.featured-video');
var win= $(window);
//var featuredDown = $('.featured-panel .down');

function requestFullscreen(element){
 if(element.requestFullScreen)
  element.requestFullScreen();
  else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen)
   element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen)
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    else if(element.msRequestFullscreen)
     element.msRequestFullscreen();
     else console.warn("fullscreen API not supported by this browser");
}

// when clicking play button
featuredButton.on('click', function() {
  // hide play button
  $(this).hide();
  // hide down button
//  featuredDown.hide();
  // hide overlay content
  featuredOverlay.fadeOut();
  // play the video
  $(this).parent().siblings(featuredVideo)[0].play();

  if (win.width() > 200) {
    requestFullscreen($(this).parent().siblings(featuredVideo)[0]);
  }
});

win.bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
  var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
  var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';
 console.log(event);
  if (event == "FullscreenOff") {
    //do something when fullscreen off
    featuredVideo.load();
    featuredOverlay.fadeIn();
    featuredButton.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-panel">
  <div class="play">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
  </div>
    <video controls="true" width="500" poster="http://lorempixel.com/500/280" class="featured-video">
       <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">
      <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv">
    </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however the only thing I could get to work was to add video .load() in addition to reloading the source.  Also, with the polyfill above, I am having no luck.  Should I add that in addition to my two lines of webkitRequestFullScreen and mozRequestFullScreen.  All of this full screen stuff is extremely confusing to me

Comment: no, the fullscreen polyfill is just a side note, the solution is the first part, where i tell you to bind the event to `document` or to `window` instead of the `featuredVideo` : in other words, replace `featuredVideo.bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',...`  with `document.bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',...`

Comment: Yea I understood that, but adding document in place of video did not work.  I solved it by calling .load() and reloading the source.  Moving on to the next issue...like you said, the full screen will not work in Firefox.  Because, I am adding the full screen event to a click event, I am not sure how to implement the polyfill above.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with `window`? This solution still does use the `.load()`, it is the same code as you're using. except this change.   For the polyfill now, or you have somewhere else in the page where you also need to request fullscreen, then you can make a `function requestFullscreen(element){`+the posted code goes here+`return element;}` or you paste this block, simply replacing `element`with `featuredVideo`. If you could edit the question with some html code, I'd give you a working snippet.

Comment: Added a sample code, note taht fullscreen won't work in snippet so you have to copy past it on your machine or server.

Comment: @user3633970, did you tried the solution in snippet?

Comment: Kaiido, yes I tried the snippet and it definitely worked!  Sorry I have been away from my computer.  Thanks for the help!